# clone a Forked project from GitHub

Tags: git, github

Would it be possible to clone a projects from Github repository which was forked by someone.

It's asking credentials as someone else has forked that particular project.

Is there a way to clone forked project by someone by ignoring credentials.

Comment: Do you want to clone it and change or just clone to use locally?

Comment: To clone and change

Comment: Then you'll have to fork first.

Comment: Nope it's asking credentials of that User who has forked that project

Comment: Is the project private? What URL do you use to clone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. You can fork the **forked project** and clone it using your credentials.

Comment: Which is not allowing to fork the forked project but instead of that forking Original project